# explanation of this pointer manipulation function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm studying pointers in C++ and here is a sample code which I found in a website :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void my_fun (int *p) {
    *p = 0;
    p++;
    *p = 4;
    p++;
    return;
}
int main ( ) {

    int a[3] = {10,20,30};
    int *p = a;
    cout << *p;
    my_fun (p);
    cout << setw(5) <<  a[0] << setw(5) << a[1] << setw(5) << a[2] << setw(5) << *p;
    return 0;
}
```

my expected result is : `10 0 4 30 30`

but I got this : `10 0 4 30 0`

would you mind please explaining what happens to the last cout ?

Comment: `p` still points to the first element of the array. The pointer `p` itself was not modified by `my_fun`. `my_fun` merely operated on a copy of `p`

Comment: This behaviour is consistent with every other type except references, which are specifically for the purpose of being an alias to an object.

Comment: You should search for and read about the difference about passing an argument *by value* and *by reference*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` still points to `a[0]`, since in `my_fun` only the local copy of the pointer is modified.
If you want to increment `p` in `my_fun` you can pass a pointer to the pointer.

```
void my_fun (int **p) {
    **p = 0;
    (*p)++;
    **p = 4;
    (*p)++;
}
```

The call then would be `my_fun (&p);`.

Comment: what if I want to modify a pointer-to-pointer ? is there something like triple pointer ?

Comment: @Javadmk ofc, just add stars